# ST_GeographyFromText() function changes the input while storing in DB- PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1

I'm working on building a database for a geo referenced application which involves storing of latitude, longitude and altitude. The column to store the same is `location` and is declared as `location geography(PointZ,4326)`.

I insert the points in the following manner

`INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT("+loc+")');`  , where `loc` is a space seperated string with the latitude , longitude and altitude values (for example 2.098 5.67 3.45).

I did not find any aberration until I inserted a specific geographical point `19.4333 99.1333 2200`, which on retrieval becomes `19.433299999999999 80.866699999999994 2200`. My concern is about the second coordinate point changing while storing.

Could someone advise me on what's the issue.

I appreciate your help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had figured out what the issue was myself when I tried to understand the specifics of `ST_GeographyFromText()` It takes in coordinates in this order - [longitude, latitude, altitude] and I had misordered latitude and longitude and as a matter of fact, the maximum value for latitude is 90 and that's the reason the `99.1333` was altered to `80.86669` ( a value less than 90 ).

Thanks!